# I get object instead of array after setting an attribute with setAttributes in React (WordPress Block Editor). What's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to dynamically create and change values of components with mapping an array. Everything works fine initially (when I map through default values) until I get to setPadding function which is supposed to set an attribiute. Then my array is changed into object making the second mapping to throw an error - `react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:103 TypeError: attributes.padding.map is not a function` . Here is the code:

The attribute:

```
padding: {
    type: 'array',
    default: [
        {   name: 'top',
            image: `${ url }images/padding-top.svg`,
            v: 10,
        },
        {
            name: 'bottom',
            image: `${ url }images/padding-bottom.svg`,
            v: 10,
        },
    ],
},
```

The component render (note `attribiutes.padding` being mapped - this works fine with default values):

```
<PanelBody
    title="Test"
    initialOpen={ true }
>
    { attributes.padding.map( ( attr ) => (
    <div className="component-row-wrapper margin-padding">
        <PanelRow>
            <RangeControl
                label={
                    <img src={ attr.image } alt="" />
                }
                value={ attr.v }
                onChange={ ( value ) => setPadding( attr.name, value ) }
                min={ 0 }
                max={ 300 }
            />
        </PanelRow>
    </div>
    ), ) }
</PanelBody>
```

And finally `setPadding` function (with `console.log` before the function itself - this is placed somewhere between `edit( props )` and component render):

```
console.log( attributes.padding ); // initially it works fine, after setPadding it logs object instead of array.

const setPadding = ( name, value ) => {
    const paddingAttr = attributes.padding;

    {paddingAttr.map( r => {
        if ( name === r.name ) {
            r.v = value;
        }
    } );}

    console.log( paddingAttr ); // works fine, being displayed as array every time!

    props.setAttributes( {
        padding: { paddingAttr }, // saves 'padding' attribute as object 'paddingAttr: Array(2)...' instead of array ??
    } );
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The `paddingAttr.map` statement does nothing, since `Array#map` is not an in-place operator. And even if you modified it to reassign the value, it still would do nothing since you don't return the value! The call to `map` returns an array of `undefined`.

Comment: @MattF. I've just looked for in-place operators and couldn't find anything. Could you give me any a link to any source so I could learn more on this, please?

So is it the cause of atrribute not being set even after correcting the object <> array error? I've changed setAttributes to 'padding: paddingAttr, value,' and it started working but is it right solution for this matter?

Comment: And now I've noticed values of those modified fields are not being saved in DB despite the attribute being modified.

Comment: Oh sorry—by in-place operator I meant "in-place operation". As in, calling `array.map(...)` wouldn't change the value of `array` (as opposed to `Array#sort` for example). You would need to change it to `array = array.map(...)` to achieve that effect.

Comment: you should try `props.setAttributes( {  padding: paddingAttr },` instead of `props.setAttributes( {
        padding: { paddingAttr }, `

Comment: @BekimBacaj I've done that after MattF. suggested it and it worked. So that means your hint is correct. This way or another thank you for your effort!

Comment: @MattF. Ah, I see! I learned a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you call `props.setAttributes`, the reason the attribute is an object is because you are creating an object! You need the following:

```js
props.setAttributes( {
  padding: paddingAttr
} );
```

Read more about property shorthand notation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

---

Additionally, as I said, you'll need to fix that call to `Array#map`. Change it to the following:

```js
paddingAttr = paddingAttr.map( r => {
  if ( name === r.name ) {
    r.v = value;
  }
  return r;
} );
```

Comment: You're right. Thank you. I corrected this but that still does nothing apart form not throwing an error anymore. Is it related to in-place operators you mentioned in your other comment?

Comment: Most likely. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I made changes which you suggested and it almost worked. The only problem left in that scenario was me using `const` instead of `let` with paddingAttr (I learned that unlike let, const is immutable - can't be updated). I changed that as well and now inputs work and values are being saved in DB. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
{paddingAttr.map( r => {
    if ( name === r.name ) {
        r.v = value;
    }
} );}
```

Here, (reason for TypeError: attributes.padding.map is not a function), paddingAttr is not array, change it to

```
{paddingAttr.default.map( r => {
    if ( name === r.name ) {
        r.v = value;
    }
} );}
```

Comment: See my comment on the question. This is a useless call to `Array#map` for two reasons.